# trigger command on wake up

Tags: raspbian, cec-client

so scenario: my pi is hooked up to a tv. When I press a button on the pi`s keyboard, I want the tv to wake up. 
I found the

```
echo on 0 | cec-client -s -d 1
```

command, but I don't know how can I wire it to fire when i touch keyboard after 2 hours of inactivity.

I only use the tv, also for the output from pi. When tv is on, screen of pi is black, but when i touch a button on keyboard, desktop comes back.

Comment: You have a second screen? Or is the TV the only screen, isnt really clear

Comment: only the tv. in hdml.

Comment: Ok, so your TV is actually powering off because it has detected no input?  If this is the case, I dont beleive there is any straight software solution, but you could do a google search about the specific brand/model of the TV to see if you find anything.  Other then that, you would need to use a relay to power cycle the TV(if it turns on with power cycle) or you could also use an IR LED to create a software controlled 'TV Remove' and have it turn the power back on that way.

Comment: Also check your TV settings, you may be able to turn off that feature.  Look for 'power-saving' mode or something to that nature.

Comment: the TV is powering off because I turn it off.. Like I watch a movie.. after it i turn it off.. but next day I want to watch another movie... If i run the script, the TV turns on fine.. I just want to bind it to some hotkey, or whatever, so when I wake up the raspi, I don't have to turn on the tv manually.